# Test if __name__ == "__main__": with click and pytest

Tags: python, python-3.x, code-coverage, pytest, coverage.py

I have the following code in `test.py`:

```
import click

@click.command()
@click.option('--text', default='hello world', help='Text to display.')
def say(text):

    print(text)


if __name__ == "__main__":

    say()
```

If I call this in the command line, it works:

```
python test.py --text=hi!
>>hi!
```

If I want to test my code, I would use:

```
from click.testing import CliRunner


runner = CliRunner()
result = runner.invoke(test.say, ['--text=blablabla'])

assert result.output == 'blablabla
```

This works too.

However, if I run my test through coverage.py, I see that the code under `if __name__ == "__main__":` is not tested. Is there a way to achieve that?

Comment: What's the point? Why would you want to test that condition? You should really ask yourself what you're trying to achieve by improving test coverage.

Comment: @yoyoyonny, I agree with you, just being a bit anal with 100% test code coverage. And this question picked my curiosity.

Comment: Well, the simplest way to get 100% is to remove `if __name__ == "__main__"` code

Comment: or add comment `# pragma: no cover` for these lines of code. If you 100% confident, of course :)

Answer (score 3):

This is what the standard library module `runpy` is for. See: https://docs.python.org/3/library/runpy.html#runpy.run_module

For example, if you have a module like `foo.bar` with `bar.py` as follows:

```
BAZ = "QUUX"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    BAZ = "ZIP"
```

Then you can write a test like:

```
import runpy

def test_bar():
    assert runpy.run_module('foo.bar')['BAZ'] == 'ZIP'
```

Or if `bar.py` is a standalone file, you can write a test like:

```
import runpy

def test_bar():
    assert runpy.run_path('bar.py')['BAZ'] == 'ZIP'
```

Comment: Is there an example?  seem not very trivial.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you didn't realize that the codes below `__name__ == "__main__"` was never invoked  by your test code

```
result = runner.invoke(test.say, ['--text=blablabla'])
```

Even if you modify the "test.py" like this, your test will not complain.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    raise RuntimeError("Something is wrong")
    say()
```

The reason is that `__name__ == "__main__"` will be false if the module file "test.py" is imported. So any codes inside the `if` clause will be ignored.

To get 100% coverage, run the command directly

```
$ coverage run test.py --text=blablabla
  blablabla
$ coverage report
  Name      Stmts   Miss  Cover                                                                                                             
  -----------------------------                                                                                                             
  test.py       6      0   100%
```

Answer (score -2):

`__name__ != "__main__"` [if you're calling this from a different module.](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/__name__-special-variable-python/)

What *should* work is:

```
import click

@click.command()
@click.option('--text', default='hello world', help='Text to display.')
def say(text):

    print(text)

say()
```

See this other SO answer if you don't want to do it this way.:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/5850364/10813463

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, which is about "if I run my test through coverage.py, I see that the code under `if __name__ == "__main__":` is not tested. Is there a way to achieve that?".