# Python Coverage Test (unitest) of doctest

Tags: python, unit-testing, doctest

I am working on covering my code with unittests.
My original code ends with:

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    import doctest
    
    doctest.testmod()
```

any idea how I cover THIS part with good tests? eager to see 100% coverage...

Comment: You can choose to ignore it if you'd like. Or check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5850268/how-to-test-or-mock-if-name-main-contents

Comment: thank you very much