# Patching __name__ in test

Tags: python, python-unittest

I do understand that you can write this in other and maybe better ways - such as moving the logic outside of `__name__ == "__main__"` blocks. I am trying to understand íf you can write it like this.

```
print(__name__)  # This will print "entrypoint"
if __name__ == "__main__":
   print("Success")  # I would like to execute this line in my test
```

```py
from unittest.mock import patch
def test_entrypoint():
   with patch("entrypoint.__name__", "__main__"):
            import entrypoint
            print(entrypoint.__name__)  # this will print correct
```

I also tried to use `entrypoint._entrypoint__name__` to check if name wrangling is the source, but that also doesn't cut it.

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5850268/how-to-test-or-mock-if-name-main-contents) suggest some options. It suggested the patch, which doesn't work. It also discusses why:

> The problem with the import statement is that the test for '**main**'
> runs as part of the import statement before you get a chance to assign
> to runpy.**name**.

But if I try the solution there (which was using `imp` now replaced by `importlib`, I am still not able to patch `__name__`.:

```
import importlib
module = importlib.import_module("__main__", "entrypoint")
```