# I don't understand the main() function in Python

Tags: python

I am a Python beginner, I started learning Python two weeks ago. In the first lecture, the professor explains the `main()` function; however, I didn't get it. I have two questions:

1. What does the `main` function do?
2. Why can't I just go back to the beginning of my program and define any function I want to use without writing a main function?

I tried searching on Google for answers; however, I didn't find anything useful.

Comment: there is no special status to a function named `main` in Python (unlike in some other languages like Java). This is just a convention. you could name your main entrypoint `banana()` and it doesn't matter, as far as Python is concerned. Or you could even not define a main entrypoint function at all (although that is typically a good idea)

Comment: Do you actually mean a `main()` function, or do you mean a function (named whatever) *and* `if __name__ == '__main__'`? The latter is a much more common idiom than naming the main function `main`.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I think you meant to say it's *not* a good idea.

Comment: I don't think I've ever written a function in python exactly called `main()` :)

Comment: yes, I meant to write, "that is typically **not** a good idea"

Comment: @InSync Many modules in the standard library actually define `main()` to be run directly--[ast](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/ast.py), [dis](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/4c4b08dd2bd5f2cad4e41bf29119a3daa2956f6e/Lib/dis.py#L1027), [timeit](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/4c4b08dd2bd5f2cad4e41bf29119a3daa2956f6e/Lib/timeit.py#L246), [gzip](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/4c4b08dd2bd5f2cad4e41bf29119a3daa2956f6e/Lib/gzip.py#L645), [webbrowser](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/4c4b08dd2bd5f2cad4e41bf29119a3daa2956f6e/Lib/webbrowser.py#L597), etc.

Comment: Please [edit] to give an example of this `main()` function and how is it used.

Comment: Perhaps see also https://stackoverflow.com/a/69778466/

Comment: Also, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17257631/why-doesnt-the-main-function-run-when-i-start-a-python-script-where-does-the

Comment: @blhsing Yes, and all of them have `if __name__ == "__main__": main()`.

Comment: @InSync My point was that your previous comment sounded like the use of a `main` function is uncommon when it is in fact common.

Comment: @blhsing I'm not saying that `main()` functions are not common, but that such a function *alone* is much less common that having *both* of it (regardless of how it is named) *and* `if __name__ == '__main__'`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unlike the `main` function in many C-derived programming languages including C, C++, C#, Objective-C and Java, a `main` function in Python has no technical significance, but is nevertheless a convention to signify the logics of a module when invoked as a script.

The `main` function in Python is idiomatically called from a name guard to ensure that its logics do not apply when the code is imported as a module, in which case [`__name__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/__main__.html#name-main) would be set to the module's name rather than `'__main__'`:

```
def main():
    ... # logics when run as a script

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

But why wouldn't one simply write those logics directly inside the name guard without defining a separate `main` function?

There are two main benefits (pun not intended):

1. It makes writing a unit test for logics guarded by the name guard much easier, since you would otherwise have to resort to all sorts of [weird loaders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5850268/how-to-test-or-mock-if-name-main-contents) in order to add the logics to your test coverage.
2. It allows other modules to import the module and run the logics guarded by the name guard much easier--the command line interface offered by a module is sometimes so much easier and friendlier to use than its other APIs that some may prefer to call the module's `main` function with command line arguments instead for convenience. If the main logics are placed directly inside a name guard then it would again be rather inconvenient like it is in reason #1.

For more examples you can refer to many common modules in the standard library such as [`ast`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/ast.py), [`dis`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/4c4b08dd2bd5f2cad4e41bf29119a3daa2956f6e/Lib/dis.py#L1027), [`timeit`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/4c4b08dd2bd5f2cad4e41bf29119a3daa2956f6e/Lib/timeit.py#L246), [`gzip`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/4c4b08dd2bd5f2cad4e41bf29119a3daa2956f6e/Lib/gzip.py#L645), [`webbrowser`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/4c4b08dd2bd5f2cad4e41bf29119a3daa2956f6e/Lib/webbrowser.py#L597), [`pdb`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/4c4b08dd2bd5f2cad4e41bf29119a3daa2956f6e/Lib/pdb.py#L2185) and so on.